# How to write format_as for enums of external namespaces in fmt 10.0

Tags: c++, fmt

For those who don't know, in fmt 10.0, they removed implicit conversions for enums for std::format. Instead you need to bring a [generic `format_as` function](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/8a4bec5cf53387356738a06ba0cf4fdf086241ae/include/fmt/format.h#L4121) to your own namespace. However having this function in your namespace alone [does not fix everything](https://godbolt.org/z/18nh8KWo7) because this function does not catch enums that exist other namespaces.

I tried implicit instantiation for enums that exist in other namespaces, [however it failed](https://godbolt.org/z/e9T6c4q5M). I tried to import external enums into my namespace using `using ExternalEnum = ExternalNS::Enum;`, it failed. I tried `using namespace ExternalNS;`, it also failed.

The only solutions I found are extending the external namespace by adding the same generic `format_as` function or implicitly casting every enum.

Is there any other solutions or if not which one is the best solution?

Comment: What's wrong with having one explicit overload per enum? Like this : https://godbolt.org/z/3fn4KocGr. This allows for flexibility, like returning specific strings for specific enums. Which I think is a good thing.

Comment: @PepijnKramer we could do that when it is necessary, however the reason I am using fmt is the simplicity and this breaking change makes using fmt much more complex. Now I have to tell everyone if you want to use an enum from another namespace, you need to implement a `format_as` function or implicitly cast enum into int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With C++20, you can provide a formatter for enums:

```
template <typename EnumType>
requires std::is_enum_v<EnumType>
struct fmt::formatter<EnumType> : fmt::formatter<std::underlying_type_t<EnumType>>
{
    // Forwards the formatting by casting the enum to it's underlying type
    auto format(const EnumType& enumValue, format_context& ctx) const
    {
        return fmt::formatter<std::underlying_type_t<EnumType>>::format(
            static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<EnumType>>(enumValue), ctx);
    }
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ebj1EndG1