# fmt failed to compile while formatting enum after upgrading to v10 and above

Tags: c++, c++11, c++20, fmt

Given code that was compiled successfully with fmt v9.1 but failed with fmt v10+

It tripped me a while before I found github issues with correct keywords `enum` and `compilation`. Also github issues are not stating version in title..
This is a defined behavior for fmt v10+

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <fmt/ostream.h>
using Test = enum Test_e{
    A,B,C
};

int main(int, char **)
{
    fmt::print(std::cout, "test enum {}\n", A);
}
```

When libfmt is upgraded to v10.0, following error messages pop up.:
[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jqbb5EarM)
[Another live demo with better layout](https://godbolt.org/z/s5aG4W7e3)
Thanks to [@Marek R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1387438/marek-r)

Related Questions in github

- https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/issues/3720
- https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/issues/3671

#### Error msg for C++11

```
In file included from <source>:2:
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/fmt/10.0.0/include/fmt/core.h: In instantiation of 'fmt::v10::detail::value<Context> fmt::v10::detail::make_value(T&&) [with Context = fmt::v10::basic_format_context<fmt::v10::appender, char>; T = Test_e&]':
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/fmt/10.0.0/include/fmt/core.h:1711:29:   required from 'fmt::v10::detail::value<Context> fmt::v10::detail::make_arg(T&&) [with bool IS_PACKED = true; Context = fmt::v10::basic_format_context<fmt::v10::appender, char>; type <anonymous> = fmt::v10::detail::type::custom_type; T = Test_e&; typename std::enable_if<IS_PACKED, int>::type <anonymous> = 0]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/fmt/10.0.0/include/fmt/core.h:1827:77:   required from 'fmt::v10::format_arg_store<Context, Args>::format_arg_store(T&& ...) [with T = {Test_e&}; Context = fmt::v10::basic_format_context<fmt::v10::appender, char>; Args = {Test_e}]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/fmt/10.0.0/include/fmt/core.h:1844:31:   required from 'constexpr fmt::v10::format_arg_store<Context, typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::type ...> fmt::v10::make_format_args(T&& ...) [with Context = basic_format_context<appender, char>; T = {Test_e&}]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/fmt/10.0.0/include/fmt/ostream.h:179:44:   required from 'void fmt::v10::print(std::ostream&, format_string<T ...>, T&& ...) [with T = {Test_e}; std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>; format_string<T ...> = basic_format_string<char, Test_e>]'
<source>:10:15:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/fmt/10.0.0/include/fmt/core.h:1691:7: error: static assertion failed: Cannot format an argument. To make type T formattable provide a formatter<T> specialization: https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#udt
 1691 |       formattable,
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/fmt/10.0.0/include/fmt/core.h:1691:7: note: 'formattable' evaluates to false
Compiler returned: 1
```

Comment: Godbolt demo: https://godbolt.org/z/s5aG4W7e3

Comment: Hi @MarekR, I included one demo in my question. https://godbolt.org/z/jqbb5EarM
Maybe it's not obvious due to not aligning to the left

Answer (score 3):

This is a defined behavior to comply `std::format`. After fmt v10+, `enum` or `enum class` must have their own specialization.

### Solutions:

1. Overload `format_as()` for specific enum
2. Cast the argument by `fmt::underlying()`
3. Overload `format_as()` for every enum (it is requires in every namespace of the enum)
4. Specialize your own `fmt::formatter<T>` (it works globally) ([Referenced answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77007114/4123703))

#### Overload `format_as()` for specific enum

Through `format_as` (refer to [Formatting User-Defined Types](https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#formatting-user-defined-types))

```
#include <fmt/format.h>

namespace kevin_namespacy {
enum class film {
  house_of_cards, american_beauty, se7en = 7
};
auto format_as(film f) { return fmt::underlying(f); }
}

int main() {
  fmt::print("{}\n", kevin_namespacy::film::se7en); // prints "7"
}
```

#### Cast the argument by `fmt::underlying()`

Eg: `fmt::print("{}",fmt::underlying(e));`

#### Overload `format_as()` for enum universally

[C++20 Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cWdbnjdjn)
Note: the overloaded `format_as()` must be in the same namespace of `enum`. In the example, enum `Test` doesn't have namespace.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <fmt/ostream.h>
using Test = enum Test_e{
    A,B,C
};

template<typename T>
requires std::is_enum_v<T>
auto format_as(T t) { return fmt::underlying(t); } 

int main(int, char **)
{
    fmt::print(std::cout, "test enum {}\n", A);
}
```

[C++11 Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/896co83v5)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <fmt/ostream.h>
using Test = enum Test_e{
    A,B,C
};

template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T>::value, bool>>
auto format_as(T t) -> typename std::underlying_type<T>::type { 
    fmt::print("enum format_as\n");
    return fmt::underlying(t); 
} 

int main(int, char **)
{
    fmt::print(std::cout, "test enum {}\n", A);
    fmt::print(std::cout, "test number{}\n", 10);
}
```

#### Specialize your own `fmt::formatter<T>`

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8dxzPdaGW) and thanks [DasMoeh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1064893/dasmoeh)'s contribution to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77007114/4123703)

```
template <typename EnumType>
requires std::is_enum_v<EnumType>
struct fmt::formatter<EnumType> : fmt::formatter<std::underlying_type_t<EnumType>>
{
    // Forwards the formatting by casting the enum to it's underlying type
    auto format(const EnumType& enumValue, format_context& ctx) const
    {
        return fmt::formatter<std::underlying_type_t<EnumType>>::format(
            static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<EnumType>>(enumValue), ctx);
    }
};
```

Comment: Nice answer. I would only suggest changing "specialize" to "overload" when referring to format_as to avoid confusion with template specialization.