# format_as with fmt enum class inside templated class

Tags: c++, fmt

I am looking for a way to implement `format_as` for a enum class inside templated class without having to use forwarder wrapper for every instantiation.
For example this works:

```
template<typename T>  
auto format_as_impl(typename S<T>::Side side) {
    switch(side) {
        case  S<T>::Side::Left:
            return "L";
        case S<T>::Side::Right:
            return "R";
    }; 
    __builtin_unreachable();    
}

auto format_as(const typename S<int>::Side& side) {
    return format_as_impl<int>(side);    
}

auto format_as(const typename S<double>::Side& side) {
    return format_as_impl<double>(side);
}
```

but trying to make this work generically blows up

```
template<typename T>  
auto format_as(typename S<T>::Side side) {
    switch(side) {
        case  S<T>::Side::Left:
            return "L";
        case S<T>::Side::Right:
            return "R";
    }; 
    __builtin_unreachable();    
}
```

> In file included from
> /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/fmt/10.2.1/include/fmt/format.h:49,
> from :9: /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/fmt/10.2.1/include/fmt/core.h: In
> instantiation of 'constexpr decltype (ctx.begin())
> fmt::v10::detail::parse_format_specs(ParseContext&) [with T =
> S::Side; ParseContext = compile_parse_context; decltype
> (ctx.begin()) = const char*]':
> /opt/compiler-explorer/libs/fmt/10.2.1/include/fmt/core.h:2684:51:
> required from here :44:15:   in 'constexpr' expansion of
> 'fmt::v10::basic_format_string<char, S::Side, S::Side,
> S::Side>("{} {} {}\012")'

If it matters I am using libfmt 10.2.1 since I know they changed something wrt enums [recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77751341/fmt-failed-to-compile-while-formatting-enum-after-upgrading-to-v10-and-above), but that does not seem like what is affecting me.
[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/3a165e3qr)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25245453/817643 I'm willing to bet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left side of `::` is a non-deduced context, which means the template parameter `T` in `S<T>::Side` can never be deduced. It must be explicitly provided when calling this function template, which fmtlib is not able to do. Thus, the function template `format_as` in question cannot be used by fmtlib.

I would recommend making `format_as` a friend function defined in `S` (the "hidden friend" idiom).

```
template<typename T>
struct S {
    // ...

    friend auto format_as(Side side) {
        switch(side) {
            case Side::Left:
                return "L";
            case Side::Right:
                return "R";
        }; 
        __builtin_unreachable();    
    }
};
```